# Java equivalent to WPF's 3D functionalities

Tags: java, .net, wpf, 3d

I've recently engaged on studying WPF (to be honest, I've gotten into it just because there was built-in 3D object, camera and rendering capabilities), which has allowed me to do this:

[image]

Download: [Master Maze](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/MasterMaze.exe)

Use directional keys ([ ↑ ] [ ↓ ] [→] [←]) to walk and turn, [Q] or [A], and [W] or [S] ("god mode") to have a broader look on the maze from above.

Note: I have no intention on harming anyone's PC. Please, would the first one to run it comment here stating that it's safe ? Or just run it on a VM.

Which I'm aware is not quite that impressive (given that there are tools that can be used to develop way smoother and more detailed little games like this one in a tenth of the time), but it was made for learning, and developing my notions in 3D development and spacial concepts.

As I'm learning Java recently, and I'm wondering: are there tools to work with 3D just as easily as in what is provided in WPF ?

For those who don't know: WPF provides the possiblity to create 3d objects, cameras, light, faces and render them (through the camera's view), and this little test game was made with fixed cubes and a camera that moves using user interaction.

**Note:** Not a dupe, it's not about Java equivalent for WPF, i'm asking specifically about the WPF's 3D functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java equilant is [Java 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_3D)

If you are writing a game then a simpler set of bindings like [LWGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Java_Game_Library) might be a more suitable choice.

Answer (score 0):

:D I did maze game using Swing in Java. My rendering was simply as it

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    buffor = (Graphics2D)g;
    double ca,sa,alfa,r,x=0,y=0,size;
    buffor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    buffor.fillRect(0,0,639,240);
    buffor.setColor(Color.GREEN);              
    buffor.fillRect(0,241,639,479);
    alfa=ga-0.52359; ///the result how we see things
    buffor.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<640;i++)
    {       
        if((map[(int)(y/64.0)][(int)(x/64.0)]=='e'))
        {
            buffor.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            buffor.drawString("EXIT",330,330);
            buffor.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        }
        ca=Math.cos(alfa); sa=Math.sin(alfa); r=0.0; x=gx; y=gy;
        while((map[(int)(y/64.0)][(int)(x/64.0)]!='x') && (map[(int)(y/64.0)][(int)(x/64.0)]!='e'))
               {
                    x=gx+r*sa;
                    y=gy+r*ca;
                    r=r+0.01;
               }
        r *= Math.cos(ga - alfa);
        size=12000/r;
        buffor.drawLine(i,240-(int)size,i,240+(int)size);
        alfa=alfa+0.00163625;
    }
    buffor.drawImage(cross,289,209,null);
    buffor.drawImage(logo,0,0,null);
    System.out.println(""+ (int)(gy/64.0) + " " + (int)(gx/64.0) + " " + ga);
}
```

There is [Java3D](https://java3d.dev.java.net/) but this is diffrent than WPF and not that easy to use IMO.

Comment: Dude, you've done a maze using hand-made polygons? me too! check this out: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/StackOverflow/labyrinth.exe